# typedef on std::function to shorten it

Tags: c++11

I want to shorten the typing of `std::function<bool(int)>` to just `func<bool(int)>` in my own namespace. It's just a personal preference.

I tried the following code below but I'm encountering syntax errors.

```
//MyHeader.hpp
template<typename S> struct func; //signature

template<typename R, typename ...Args>
struct func<R(Args...)>;

template<typename R, typename ...Args>
//typename typedef std::function<R(Args...)> func; // <R(Args...)>;
using func = std::function<R(Args...)>;  //<---closes to solve.


//SomeClass.cpp
func<bool(int)> f;
func<void()> g = [] {
    //some code here...
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It was just missing the include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is a bit too complicated, you might want to use the [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) like this

```
#include <functional>

template <class Fct> using func = std::function<Fct>;
```

which you can instantiate the in the desired way:

```
int test(bool) { return 1; }

func<int(bool)> f(test);
funct<void()> g = [](){};
```

Comment: Additional question, is the `int(bool)` considered as 1 template argument or 2?

Comment: Functions have a type, which becomes visible when you bind function pointers to variables. Lambdas have a type, too, known to the compiler. Hence, the instantiation here happens with one type. It's a good question though, and I just realized, that variadic templates aren't necessary in the alias signature.

Comment: I ran a test code and it confirms that `int(bool)` is just 1 template argument. So this is also a solution `template <class A> using func = std::function<A>;`

Comment: That's the same :) The compiler does not care which name you chose

Comment: I guess the variadic version is a general solution in case `std::function` added extra optional template arguments in the future. But currently, it seems `std::function` only have 1 template argument.

Comment: @L.F. It's due to timing of posting the comment actually. He finished editing his solution and posting comment before I finished and posted my comment. So it's my comment to his 1st version of solution. =) But I leave it anyway for the sake of history.

Comment: @acegs Sorry :P

Comment: @lubgr I think the variadic template version is better. =)